# Identify unique values in range based on criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I want to identify unique flows based upon values in multiple columns in each rows. Both rows and columns are dynamic. My data looks like:

```
Record1,Record2,Record3,Record 4,Record 5
A,B,C,D,E
A,B,C,F,G
A,B,C,F,I
A,B,J,K,H
A,M
X,Y,Z
X,Y,A
```

I have to derive flow diagram based on these values. So Flowdiagram would look like.
e.g. A,B,C is common so will not be repeated and C will have 2 children, D and F, and F will have two children, G and I:

```
A-> B -> C -> D -> E
           -> F -> G
                -> I
      -> J -> K -> H
  -> M
X -> Y -> Z
       -> A
```

Comment: By dynamic columns you mean that the number of columns could change?

Comment: Hi Marco, Yes, i am generating this worksheet from another hence number of column will differ.

Comment: Can you maybe elaborate your question a bit more? Will the layout always be like this? Will the rows always be sorted ascended?

Comment: Hi Marco, Layout will be same as i have written macro to derive this sheet. Hence the number of rows and columns will differ but the layout will be same. Also i am sorting columns sequentially (Key 1 - record 1,Key 2 - record 2, Key 3 - record 3 .. other keys). I want to derive flows based on the combination of each column as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Sub CreateFlowChart()

```
Application.Worksheets("Record_sorting").Select
Dim arrTwoD()
Dim intRows
Dim intCols
Dim ShapeText
Dim ShapeType As MsoAutoShapeType
ShapeType = msoShapeFlowchartProcess

Dim i As Integer
Dim t, k, l As Integer
Dim shp As Shape
t = 0
k = 0
l = 0
intRows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
intCols = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

Application.Worksheets("FlowChart").Select
If ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count > 2 Then
    DeleteAllAutoShapes
End If
ReDim Preserve arrTwoD(1 To intRows, 1 To intCols)

For i = 2 To UBound(arrTwoD, 1)
    t = 12
    k = k + l + 72
    l = 72
    For j = 1 To UBound(arrTwoD, 2)
        arrTwoD(i, j) = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j)
        Application.Worksheets("Record_sorting").Select
        ShapeText = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j)
        If ShapeText <> "" Then

            Application.Worksheets("FlowChart").Select
            Set m_Worksheet = ActiveSheet
            Randomize

            Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(ShapeType, k, t, 130, l)

            AddFormattedTextToShape shp, (ShapeText)

            If CInt(Application.Version) >= 12 Then
                If i = 25 Then
                     ' Treat as line
                    shp.ShapeStyle = msoLineStylePreset1
                Else
                     ' Randomly select a style
                    shp.ShapeStyle = Int(Rnd() * 42 + 1)
                 End If
             End If
             t = t + 85
        End If
    Next
Next

Application.Worksheets("FlowChart").Select
```

End Sub

Public Sub AddFormattedTextToShape(oShape As Shape,sText As String)
    If Len(sText) > 0 Then
        With oShape.TextFrame
            .Characters.Text = sText
            .Characters.Font.Name = "Calibri (Body)"
            .Characters.Font.Size = 9
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignCenter
            .VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
        End With
    End If
End Sub

Comment: above code gives me something like
A-> B -> C -> D -> E
A-> B - -> F -> G
A-> B - -> F -> I
A-> B -> J -> K -> H
A -> M
X -> Y -> Z
X -> Y -> A